# Why isn't my div rendering and instead is grayed out in the inspector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to show some content that's inside of a div but for some reason when I use the chrome debug tools to inspect the code, it's just grayed out.

I can't see anything that's inside the class `modal` why is that?

```css
#mainDiv {
    margin: 10px;
}

.modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.modal{
    background-color: white;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>EasyModal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
            <h1>Easy Modal</h1>
            <Button id="modal-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</Button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-bg">
        <div class="modal">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="text">
            <button>Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: follow the steps for modals in bootstraps documentation if you are going to use it.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Chrome 76.0.3809

Comment: Look at your code, you have .modal-bg visible and takes up the entire page.... of course it is going to cover the page and make it gray.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Same here, entire code is working. The 'Buy Now' button is greyed out too though.

Comment: @the_ritz Of course it is. There is a modal covering the page. I don't think the OP understands what a modal is.

Comment: Look at the answer.

Comment: That modal is not bootstraps, should be like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#static-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to modal class. If you inspect, you'll observe that there is a `display: none;` property in modal class, which i guess is default bootstrap .modal class.

To solve this, use a different name for .modal class.

Comment: Oh wow that's really interesting! I'm going to look into the bootstrap modal class a little bit now to see what's it all about, thank you!